# Getting some badges

Tags: support

How do you get the following badges?

- **Cleanup**: First rollback. What is rollback?
- **Analytical**: Visited every section of the FAQ (retired)
  Does that mean i can no longer get that badge? well i have seen that the badge was recently awarded to someone 14 hrs. ago..

So how do you get these badges?

https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges here's how i came to know about these badges...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/2677158/steven-mastandrea How did he get the Analytical Badge?

Comment: As for the recent awards: probably account merge side-effects?

Comment: @MichaelGrubey: Account merge. If an account that *already* has the badge is merged into one that doesn't, the badge is re-awarded.

Comment: okay thankyou people...!!